# Do shield and armor check modifiers stack?

Tags: dnd-4e, skills, equipment, shield

If I wear Hide armor (Check -1) and use a Heavy Shield (Check -2) is my check -2 or -3?

In other words, do the checks stack or do I use the highest negative?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

They do stack. You won't find any help in the rules for Armor or Shields, but the Rules Compendium (p 314) has a general entry for penalties:

> **Penalty** 
>   A number subtracted from a die roll. Unlike bonuses, penalties don’t have types. Penalties add together, unless they’re from the same named game element (such as a power or a trait).

Shields and Armor are different game elements, so the penalties stack.

Answer (score 10):

The short answer is the penalties stack.

Source: page 275 of *Player's Handbook* states:

> Penalties: Unlike bonuses, penalties don’t have types. Penalties add together, unless they’re from the same power. If two monsters attack you with the same power and each causes you to take a penalty to a particular roll or score, you don’t add the penalties together; you take the worst penalty.

On this page, it also separates out armor bonuses and shield bonuses (or conversely penalties).

Comment: +1, the PHBs are the only books I have access to currently and I couldn't find this for the life of me; thanks!